# Error dialog won't dismiss with IBM Cloud node-red on outdate node.js configuration

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, node-red

I had a demo that used to work on IBM Cloud and now it doesn't. I'm not sure if this is even the problem ... but I can't figure out how to get this error (Using an unsupported version of Node.js  You should upgrade to the latest Node.js LTS release) to go away. Why doesn't the error go away in the first place (dismiss the box). The warning triangle to the right links to nothing.

I read this to fix it : [IoTP boilerplate Node RED complains about unsupported version of Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746392/iotp-boilerplate-node-red-complains-about-unsupported-version-of-node-js/57897652#57897652) but have no idea how to do this

Here is a screen cap of what's going on:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjrmYxA_2hoGh_FEI7bsXW6O_mKHmg

Comment: Please use the built in image hosting then pictures can be inlined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable [Continuous delivery](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/continuous-delivery) mode for your application.

This will give you a git repository for your deployed application along with a web based editor that will allow you to make the change to the file.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't . realize you answered this and found out how to do it and posted my answer to my question. Unreal there aren't simple instructions attached to the error to do that ... but alas